Why won't by WSL generate a scaffold when I prompted ```npx create-solana-dapp```. It generates a syntax error. What could be wrong?
/home/ekomblockchain/.npm/_npx/07c7a862db1a1c86/node_modules/@clack/prompts/dist/index.cjs:6
;case"submit":return${n}${color.gray(S_BAR)}  ${color.dim(this.value||t.placeholder)};case"cancel":return${n}${color.gray(S_BAR)}  ${color.strikethrough(color.dim(this.value??""))}${this.value?.trim()?`
^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token '?'
at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:915:16)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:963:27)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:14)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:887:19)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:85:18)
at Object. (/home/ekomblockchain/.npm/_npx/07c7a862db1a1c86/node_modules/create-solana-dapp/dist/bin/index.cjs:4:17)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:999:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)

Hi there, in order to make it more clear what the actual issue is, please provide more data.
Please provide the full output of the command you're running, not only the part that you think is relevant. In addition, please provide the version of Node and the package manager you're using to get into this situation.
